# BeautifulSoup - парсинг сайта

Tags: python, парсер, csv, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/page/3'


def parse(url):
   news = []
   response = requests.get(url)
   html = response.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
   products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cat_news_item'})
   for product in products:
      title = product.find('a')
      date = product.find('span')
      news.append({
        'name': [name.text for name in product.find_all('a')]
    })
      for i in news:
         print(i)

      with open('zakon.csv', 'w') as files:
          opp = csv.writer(files)
          opp.writerows(i)


print(parse(url))
```

не могу понять, в чем проблема, почему информации неправильно записывается в csv файл.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос текущий результат и какой должен быть

Comment: И еще, подправьте отступы в коде, т.к. в текущем виде код не рабочий

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы создавали *словарь* для вывода данных, я предполагаю, что вы хотели вывод в формате JSON, а не в формате CSV.

Для этого импортируйте json:

```
import json
```

и запишите в него так:

```
with open('zakon.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as files:
    json.dump(news, files, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Файл `zakon.json` будет после этого выглядеть так (начало):

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "name": []
>   },
>   {
>     "name": [
>       "Китай взял пример с США и ударил по Microsoft"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "name": [
>       "Крысы захватили столичный микрорайон"
>     ]
>   },
>   {
>     "name": [
>       "\"Дала пощечину и зажала рот\". Няня призналась, как укладывала ребенка спать"
>     ]
>   },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки здесь:

```
for i in news:
    print(i)

with open('zakon.csv', 'w') as files:
    opp = csv.writer(files)
    opp.writerows(i)
```

Первая:

После цикла `for i in news:` в переменной `i` остается только последний элемент списка `news` - и только этот элемент вы записываете в файл `zakon.csv`.

Вторая:

`opp.writerows()` ожидает параметр iterable (например список, кортеж, словарь) строк, причем каждая строка репрезентирует одну строку для выводного файла. Вы дали как параметр `i`, что - как я написал выше - последний элемент списка словарей, т.е. *словарь*.

Итерация словарей идет по *ключам*, и в вашем словаре только один ключ - `'name'`. Так как тот ключ является *строкой*, он интерпретируется как список символов `['n', 'a', 'm', 'e']` и записывается в выходной файл как `n,a,m,e` - что вы и получили, хотя не хотели.

Исправление:

```
with open('zakon.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as files:
    opp = csv.writer(files)

    for i in news:
        print(i)
        if i['name']:                # Когда список непустой 
            opp.writerow(i['name'])  # Или какой-то другой список (ваши только 1-элементные)
```

Файл `zakon.csv` будет после этого выглядеть так (начало):

> ```
> Китай взял пример с США и ударил по Microsoft
> Крысы захватили столичный микрорайон
> """Дала пощечину и зажала рот"". Няня призналась, как укладывала ребенка спать"
> Зеленский и Путин встретятся до пресс-конференции нормандского саммита
> "Идеальное место, чтобы выкинуть ребенка - алматинцы о страшной находке"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Может выть, что вы хотели:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.zakon.kz/news/page/3'


def parse(url):
    news = []
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'cat_news_item'})
    for product in products:
        title = product.find('a')
        date = product.find('span')
        if title:
            news.append([date.text, title.text])

    with open('zakon.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as files:
        opp = csv.writer(files)
        opp.writerows(news)

parse(url)
```

Файл `zakon.csv` будет после этого выглядеть так (начало):

> ```
> 23:55,"Автобусные полосы в Алматы открыли для такси, но по ним никто не ездит"
> 23:37,Котлован под фундамент высотки вырыли в нескольких шагах от четырехэтажки
> 23:02,Семьям погибших вахтовиков выплатили по миллиону
> 22:46,В молочном союзе рассказали о требованиях к производителям молока
> 22:15,Бывшие вице-министры энергетики предстанут перед судом еще до конца года
> 21:36,"Сотрудники ""неотложки"" спасли из горящего дома двоих детей"
> ```